# How does Yahoo! determine if cookies are enabled?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, yahoo

I am trying to automate logging into Yahoo! as an OpenID provider using cURL in PHP. When I do so, Yahoo! informs the program that it needs to enable cookies. Cookie support is enabled and I have confirmed that Yahoo! sends a `DK` cookie which the program is sending back.

When I do the process manually in Chrome, I get a `B` cookie instead. When the login form is submitted, Yahoo normally sends a bunch of other cookies in a 302 response, but when my program submits the form Yahoo doesn't send any more cookies and delivers the login form again.

I've noticed a number of other things in the page that generate cookies (presumably for cross-domain authentication and ad tracking) and I tried querying those for more cookies but it didn't help. Why doesn't Yahoo set the same cookies for my program as it does for Chrome? What else can I try?

Comment: like anyone else - they try to set a cookie, redirect the user, and see if the cookie comes back.

Comment: But I gave them their cookie back and they still didn't like it.

Comment: C is for cookie, that's good enough for me
C is for cookie, that's good enough for me
C is for cookie, that's good enough for me
Oh, cookie, cookie, cookie starts with C

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping it wouldn't be the user agent, but it is. The cURL call was setting a particular user agent for internal testing but apparently Yahoo's login page is different and broken unless it gets a user agent that it expects. Setting it to my actual user agent while running tests magically fixed the problem.